# Align Navbar Items correctly with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to align my Navbar Items in a Certain Way. Currently the Navbar looks like this:

[image]

I want that the Navbar is aligned like this:

Logo ---------------------- About  Blog Writeups ------------------------- Sign Up Sign In

This is my current Navbar Component:

```
<Navbar bg={backgroundColor} variant="dark" expand="md" fixed="top">
    <Container className='navbar-container'>
      <Navbar.Brand className="ml-auto" href="/">Logo</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ms-auto">
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/blog">Blog</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/writeups">Writeups</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn")} href="/sign-up">Sign Up</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item >
            <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn btn-primary")} href="/sign-in">Sign In</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
```

With the mentioned code it now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Navbar bg={backgroundColor} variant="dark" expand="md" fixed="top">
    <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">Logo</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ms-auto d-flex w-100">
                <Nav.Item className="ms-auto">
                    <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/blog">Blog</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/writeups">Writeups</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item className="ms-auto">
                    <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn")} href="/sign-up">Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item >
                    <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn btn-primary")} href="/sign-in">Sign In</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
</Navbar>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This only puts everything in the middle and the logo ontop of all childs in <Nav>, i added how it looks with your code in the top post

Comment: I have added a output image with the answer how the code looks like.  This will according to your wanted concept            Logo ---------------------- About Blog Writeups ------------------------- Sign Up Sign In

Comment: I think you modified your container class CSS with flex-direction: column; Thats why this kind of output is generated. Unlinked your custom CSS file and try again. I hope your problem will gone.

Comment: I already tried that and commented the custom css file, but there is no change and it looks like in the picture i uploaded

Comment: See the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-newton-mo9kj2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think you have something from your CSS. Disconnect your CSS from your component.

Comment: Well i added the fluid attribute to the container and now it seems to work